# Firebase authentication not being called and returns a null user (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've just started to learn swift 3 and I came from .NET background.
I am having trouble authenticating users using firebase with my application. I was trying to create a general function which in turns call another Firebase function.

```
    let user = logIn(email: email, password: password)
    if user != nil{
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MainVC(), animated:   true)
    }
```

```
 

    func logIn(email: String,password: String) -> Firebase.User? {
            var loginUser:Firebase.User?

            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
                if(error != nil){
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }


                if let firebaseUser = user {
                    loginUser = firebaseUser
                }
            }
            if let user = loginUser{
                return user
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
```

During my debugging, I found the **Auth.auth().signIn** function skipped and not been executed by some how and returns null. however, when I run the application again, I found the firebase authenticate my user!!!

Comment: I would make something like this inside the logIn function: `Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
              print(error!)
              return
            }
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MainVC(), animated:   true)
          }` without returning anything, just present the view controller.

Comment: That would work but what the problem with my code why Auth function doesn't get through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `signIn` is async function, which takes some time to execute. That means that when you call your `logIn` function, before signIn is able to sign you in, your `else { return nil}` executes and the returned value is nil.

You shouldn't return from this function, what you should do instead is use a callback: So replace your function header with this.

`func logIn(email: String,password: String, callback: @escaping (Firebase.User?) -> ()) {`

Remove the last `if` in your function because you don't need it, everything will be handled in the `signIn`block.

Replace the code inside `signIn` block with:

```
if error != nil {
  print(error!)
  callback(nil)
}

if let firebaseUser = user {
  callback(firebaseUser)
}
```

Now you have to change the way you are calling your `logIn` function into:

```
logIn(email: yourEmail, password: yourPassword) { (firebaseUser: Firebase.User?) in
  // Your result is saved in firebaseUser variable
}
```

**Whole code together**

```
// CALL LOGIN FUNCTION

logIn(email: yourEmail, password: yourPassword) { (firebaseUser: Firebase.User?) in
  // Your result is saved in firebaseUser variable
  if firebaseUser != nil{
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MainVC(), animated:   true)
  }

}

// LOGIN FUNCTION

func logIn(email: String,password: String, callbacK: @escaping (Firebase.User?) -> ()) {
  Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    if error != nil {
      print(error!)
      callback(nil)
    }

    callback(firebaseUser)
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this so maybe you will have to make some small modifications but this is the right way of doing it. I hope you get the idea.